# Not able to access SVN repository via SVN protocol, but can access with http

Tags: svn, collabnet, svnserve, svn-server

I am not able to access SVN repository via SVN protocol, but can access with http:

I have the following setup

1) I am using collabnet subversion 1.6.20 Installed at server830(windows 2003)
Defined environment variable: Path = C:\Program Files\CollabNet\Subversion Server
Configured a windows service -> C:\Program Files\CollabNet\Subversion Server\svnserve.exe --service -r C:\svn_repository\webMethods_SVN
Which is running at present
I have created a repository named "webMethods_SVN" and I can access my repository and its contents via
    http://server830.com/svn/webMethods_SVN/

But the same I am not able to access it through
        svn://server830.com/svn/webMethods_SVN/

2) My desktop is on other remote server I have installed tortoise SVN and can access server830 SVN Repository via Tortoise SVN Repo browser svn://plvm830
Tortoise SVN is also asking me for authentication details and validating me before access to the repository.

Could any one please suggest me how to access my Repository created at server830 via SVN protocol locally and remotely ??

Answer (score 0):

Just notes:

- If you have http-served repository, I can't see strong reasons also maintain svnserve'd access
- If you can reach svn:// repository from remote, but can't from localhost, you must to find blocking reason for localhost (and check if svnserve listen on all interfaces /it must do it, but.../ - `netstat -na` and check string with port 3690)
- `-r PATH` parameter for svnserve define **common root** of repositories in case of multi-repository setup (read [Svnserve Based Server](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-serversetup-svnserve.html)), not repository directory
- svn:// and http:// type repository **does not share** common part of URL as a rule, for good and correct `--service -r C:\svn_repository\` and repository webMethods_SVN under root svn:// URL will be

`svn://localhost/webMethods_SVN` for local access

`svn://<KNOWN-NAME>/webMethods_SVN` for remote access